# Why are password fields usually not autofilled in $_POST?

Tags: html, forms, security, post

In many websites that do not use AJAX, registration forms usually keep all the input data filled upon failed attempts, however, more often than not, the password field has to be refilled by the user.

My question is, why do web developers choose to do this? My first idea was that they are trying to prevent malicious scripts from stealing the password on page load, however, they can just as easily do this with an `onKeyUp`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I imagine the idea behind it is that a response should never contain a password.  If the value of the input is set in the response, then the response contains a password.

Comment: This seems to be browser behavior more than anything.

Comment: it's a good security practice , passwords shouldn't be saved or ready for autocompletion (depends on your degree of paranoia) , and in case he uses a very simple password that doesn't meet security requirements, why bother keeping it at all ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers have a feature specifically for passwords, and are saved **ONLY** if the user explicitly allows the browser to. Most browsers *will* ask 'Do you want to store the password?'

You could further keep a master password to protect the saved passwords when a user is not on his/her machine.

IMO, I do not find it wrong to save passwords, because, since I let the browser save my password, I generally tend to have **much** stronger passwords, since I tend to use autogenerated passwords, which are usually difficult to remember. Also, it helps my keeps me away from using a single variation of the password for multiple websites.

There are various ways through which you might be able to sniff the password, irrespective of whether you save it or not. Sites usually have a password restore feature, that would link to, say my mobile phone, in case of a password breach.

So, the website *should*  allow the user to save the password in the browser, and this puts the responsibility on the user, and it is HIS/HER decision how he/she wants to use the password.

Answer (score 1):

Because to auto-fill a field, if you look at the markup, you'd see something like `<input type="password" value="YOURPASSWORDHERE" />` which is not so great for security.  Getting markup is easier than monitoring the JS events in terms of XSS, as I can request a page easier than I can manipulate the DOM with JS.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't about scripts, the website needs to trust scripts running in its context.

Browsers often cache the page markup. You probably don't want to have your password in the cache.